# Comparing letter occurrence with comparator

Tags: sorting, java-8, java-stream, comparator

I am having a problem with sorting a string array[], based on which strings have most letter 'p' in them, i.e., `s1 (apple)` would be before `s2 (ape)...`

I am learning how to implement Comparator to do this and use then s1.compareTo(s2) and lambda. The big question is, can't I somehow use a stream to do this ?

This is how I did it for my String array COUNTRIES in reversed alphabetic sorting

```
Comparator<String> reverseAlphabetic = (s1,s2) -> -s1.compareToIgnoreCase(s2);   

Arrays.sort(COUNTRIES,reverseAlphabetic);
System.out.println("\nCountries in reverse alphabetic order");
for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
    System.out.println("\t"+COUNTRIES[i]);
```

Comment: The short answer is - yes, you can

Comment: Never use minus in comparators. When `compareToIgnoreCase` happens to return `Integer.MIN_VALUE`, trying to flip the sign will overflow and end up again at `Integer.MIN_VALUE`. When you want to reverse the order, just use `s2.compareToIgnoreCase(s1)`. Or use the already existing comparator: `Comparator<String> reverseAlphabetic = String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER.reversed();`

Answer (score 1):

Y̶o̶u̶ ̶c̶a̶n̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶s̶o̶m̶e̶t̶h̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶l̶i̶k̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶:̶

```
Comparator<String> comparator = (str1, str2) ->
        ((str1.length() - str1.replaceAll("p", "").length()) -
         (str2.length() - str2.replaceAll("p", "").length()));
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("ape", "apple", "appple");
list.sort(comparator);
```

Actually my solution had fundamental mistakes. [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) commented a solution in my deleted answer.

```
list.sort(Comparator
         .comparingLong((String s) -> s.chars().filter(c -> c == 'p').count()).reversed());
```

commented by [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger)

*Your first variant is broken too, as `a - b - c - d` is not the same as `a - b - (c - d)`. It just produces the desired result by accident; a different original order will lead to different results. Yet another reason not to use minus when you mean, e.g. `Integer.compare(…, …)`. A correct and efficient comparator can be as simple as `Comparator.comparingLong(s -> s.chars().filter(c -> c=='p').count())` (or to have most occurences first, `Comparator.comparingLong((String s) -> s.chars().filter(c -> c=='p').count()).reversed())`, though a old-fashioned counting loop would be even better*

Comment: After you inserted the brackets, the first variant does the right thing, but it must be emphasized that using minus only works here, because we can preclude negative numbers for the string length or occurrences of `p`, so the distance between two counts will never overflow. It’s not the right tool for comparisons in general.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for your attention even for small things.